# Handle view load time and print out results

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I am in the phase of my iOS SwiftUI app where I am going through and checking to improve performance and such, are there any tools or any way for me to track `View` load times and print them out?

Example:

```
struct ContinueWithGoogleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GoogleSignInButton()
            .accessibilityIdentifier("GoogleSignInButton")
            .accessibility(hint: Text("Sign in with Google button."))
    }
}
```

`ContinueWithGoogleView()` took `9.27364ms` to load view, etc..

Comment: You can use Xcode Profile for these operations

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/16126261-instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started. Time Profiler is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Xcode Profile for these operations. There is a good guideline for [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/16126261-instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started).

`Time Profiler` is what you are looking for.

> I recommend you to look at XCode Instruments for different processes that will develop your application like Allocations and controlling memory leaks

Comment: I’m not sure that Time Profiler is actually the right tool for the OP’s question. But, there is a SwiftUI specific tool.

Comment: @SLE It's called "SwiftUI"